# painting issue when porting lwuit to codename one

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, codenameone

I am porting my lwuit app to [Codename one](http://www.codenameone.com)

However, my forms are not getting painted correctly in the emulator . Why is this happening?

For example, below you can see a straight black line cutting through the letters. How to prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select zoom 100% in the skin to avoid painting artifacts and do not resize the skin.